# GNAT Studio 2021 Community Edition Software Bug?

Tags: ada

Hopefully this is a quick fix and I am sure it's nothing that AdaCore have messed up on.

I have been using GNAT Com 2021 since it's release and have never had  a problem with it, until now. So basically, I create  a new project "Simple Ada Project" name it, choose the save directory as I always have. The IDE loads the project and gives me the default template of "Main.adb" as I expect it would.

Now, here lies the issue. When I compile this template, it works fine, links and executes. ONLY  the first time.

Source Code:

```
procedure Main is

begin
   --  Insert code here.
   null;
end Main;
```

Compiler:

```
gprbuild -d -PC:\Users\Amynu\OneDrive\Documents\Ada\test.gpr
Compile
   [Ada]          main.adb
Bind
   [gprbind]      main.bexch
   [Ada]          main.ali
Link
   [link]         main.adb
[2021-12-02 10:49:33] process terminated successfully, elapsed time: 06.05s
```

If I attempt to modify the code, even the slightest way such as:

```
with Ada.Text.IO;

procedure Main is

begin
    Ada.Text_IO.Put("Hello Ada!");
end Main;
```

I always get greeted with this message:

```
gprbuild -d -PC:\Users\Amynu\OneDrive\Documents\Ada\test.gpr C:\Users\Amynu\OneDrive\Documents\Ada\src\main.adb
Compile
   [Ada]          main.adb
main.adb:1:01: error: compilation unit expected
gprbuild: *** compilation phase failed
[2021-12-02 10:54:51] process exited with status 4, elapsed time: 00.84s
```

Bare in mind this is a completely fresh install of the software, the first program I am creating, using the default template, no other files, procedures or functions exist. Only "compilation unit" is Main - which it clearly found and compiled before I modified it.

Does anyone know what is causing this issue? Is there a setting I have toggled by accident before the re-install? I have never had this problem before. I have tired everything to get the compiler to see "Main" after I modified it, but nothing seems to work. I even attempted to place the definition of Main into a Package and call it that way, but same result.

Is it a software bug that has just appeared? Do Ada Core know about it?

Please help if anyone can.

Comment: Not sure if this is a bug, but it seems that you are building in a folder on OneDrive. Is the behavior reproducible when you build in a folder not stored on OneDrive?

Comment: Yes, I still get the error. In addition, when I re-opened the project to test this, all the code in Main had bee replaced with this: p  b  e  Not sure what that is about! It looks as though the project is corrupting when I build it.

Comment: What happens if you `gprbuild main`, i.e. using the default `.gpr` file?